# How to enter data to the spanner table?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I have a spanner table `report_config`.
Which looks something like:

```
+----------------------+--------------+
|         col_name     |  data_type   |
+----------------------+--------------+
| report_id            | INT64        |
| report_name          | string       |
| report_type          | string       |
+----------------------+--------------+
```

Now `report_id` is the primary key. And it has entries like:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| report_id   |  report_name |  report_type |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1           | report1      | 1st_report   |
| 2           | report2      | 2nd_report   |
| 10          | report10     | 10th_report  |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

The issue happens in while I try to insert a new row with `report_id=3` into the table:
Error `Statement failed: Row [3] in report_config was already inserted in this transaction.`

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that you are inserting the same row twice in the same transaction. Can you share the code that you use to execute the insert?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you've already inserted the row at least once in the same transaction. Please check you application to see if you accidentally perform this write/insert more than once.